# How to reduce size of app with arcgis dependency?

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-runtime

I'm starting to work on an iOS app, which should use ArcGIS. I've added a hello world style (1 screen, 1 map without any extra stuff) basic implementation, and now my app size is trough the roof. I've followed [this](https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/latest/swift/guide/install.htm) tutorial for the setup.

A development build app size on the iPhone X used to be 50Mb (it's not a very complex app), now it's 510Mb. An archive is 750Mb.
I'm not sure if the release process (Appstore upload) would reduce that (I guess not).

Here is my Podfile

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED')
        config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED')
    end
end

target 'AppName' do
   pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 4.8.0'
   pod 'RxSwift',    '~> 4.2.0'
   pod 'RxCocoa',    '~> 4.2.0'
   pod 'HockeySDK',  '~> 5.1.2'
   pod 'XCGLogger', '~> 6.0.4'
   pod 'Floaty', '~> 4.0.1'
   pod 'CTPanoramaView', '~> 1.1'
   pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.7.3'
   pod 'ArcGIS-Runtime-SDK-iOS', '100.3'
end
```

The app size of the [SDK Sample](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/arcgis-runtime-sdk-samples/id1180714771?mt=8) in the appstore is 100Mb on my iPhone X, so I guess that would be a more reasonable size for my app too.

What steps could I do to reduce the app size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The impact should be about 65-70Mb. You're probably looking at the Universal ipa. Please see this answer to a similar question and let us know if that helps: [iOS ArcGIS.framework too large, hence large .ipa size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50488350/ios-arcgis-framework-too-large-hence-large-ipa-size/50594322#50594322)