# iOS ArcGIS.framework too large When making ipa File. How to reduce the size of iap file

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-server, arcgis-runtime

I am maintaining an application with ArcGIS.framework for iOS.When am creating an .ipa files its file size is very large[92 mb] . i have to reduce the size of an .ipa file  to bellow 50 mb.

Answer (score 0):

The Runtime will add about 70MB to your app. Note that this compresses down so the over-the-air download size may be much smaller (perhaps about 25-30MB).

Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50594322/1416253 for some more insight.

Can you explain why you specifically need to hit 50MB?

Comment: App Thinning time  can't upload to the Appstore. only i can take Adhoc certified ipa files.